# What's the difference between tag.class and tag .class?

Tags: css

What's the difference between

`tag.class` and `tag .class`

or

`tag#id` and `tag #id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tag.class` matches all elements with name `tag` **and** with the class `class`, e.g.:

> `div.foo { color: red; }` matches `<div class="foo">`

`tag .class` matches all `.class` elements that **are descendants**  of `tag` elements (note the space between `tag` and `.class`):

(Remember that "descendants" includes all children, their children, and so on - whereas, in comparison, the `>` (child selector) only selects immediate children and not any grandchildren.)

> `div .foo { color: red; }` matches the `<span>` in `<div><p><span class="foo">`

`tag#id` and `tag #id` are similar to the above, except matching on the `id` attribute instead of the `class` attribute[1]

> `div#foo { color: red; }` matches `<div id="foo">`
>
> `div #foo { color: red; }` matches the `<span>` in `<div><p><span id="foo">`

Remember that because `id=""` attributes are meant to be unique that additional selectors may be superfluous, e.g. `div#bar` could be simplified to just `#bar` (unless you're reusing the same CSS rules on different pages where `#bar` may have different element tag names).

[1]: This is true in HTML, in other SGML and XML languages using CSS the `.class` and `#id` selectors can be mapped to other attribute names.

Answer (score 2):

`tag.class` would mean a `tag` with `class='class'`. Something like this:

```
<!-- This tag would be selected -->
<tag class="class">
    ...
</tag>
```

`tag .class` would mean an element whose `class='class'`, and is a descendant of a `<tag>`. Something like this:

```
<tag>
    ...
        <!-- This div would be selected -->
        <div class="class">
        </div>
    ...
</tag>
```

In general, something like `selector1 selector2` would mean an element that matches `selector2` and is a descendant of an element that matches `selector1`. Consider this example:

**CSS:**

```
/*
   div.face matches a div with class="face"
   div.eye#left matches a div with class="eye" and id="left"

   Hence, this would select an element with class="eye" and id="left" which is
   inside a div with class="face"
*/

div.face div.eye#left {
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="face">  <!-- div.face -->

  <div class="upper">

    <div class="eye" id="left"></div> <!-- div.eye#left is selected -->
    <div class="eye" id="right"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Descendant, not child. `tag > .class` would be a child.

Answer (score 1):

Space () is a descendant selector, see documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

Long story short `tag.class` applies to a `tag` element **with** class `class`, whereas `tag .class` applies to any elements with `class` class that are within `tag` element.